# Problem while using bibtex reference of a url

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, urls

```
 @online{senfus,
title={article name},
 url= {https://m**.s*/U****d/Om%20MPB/F****g/Kxyzy.pdf},
 }
```

While citing this reference, I am getting following error because of the term "%" in the url.

> Paragraph ended before \BR@@bibitem was complete.\par

Is using tinyurl/google url shortener a good idea for citing the article's url.

Answer (score 12):

You did not mention which bibliography style you use, but most styles wrap the content of the `url` field in a `\url{...}` macro, and provide a very basic definition for it that can not handle special characters like `%`.

The solution is to simply load the `url` or `hyperref` package, as those define sophisticated versions of the `\url` macro that do handle special characters.

Comment: Using 'IEEEtran' bibliography style

Comment: Then using the `url` or `hyperref` package should indeed work.

Comment: It's strange because I'm using these packages and still get errors with '%' characters

Answer (score 10):

You need to escape the `%` in your bib file because the `%` symbol has special meaning in LaTeX. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics#Reserved_Characters.

Try replacing `%` with `\%` in the URL field in the bib file.

Comment: It doesn't work! Still getting the same error.

Comment: `#` also need to be escaped (`\#`)

Comment: Escaping symbols such as `&`, `#`, and `%` in a URL string pretty much guarantees that the URL string can't be made into a hyperlink if the `hyperref` package is loaded. It's much better -- certainly much less work in the medium to long term -- to encase the entire URL in a `\url{..}` directive.

Comment: I would add that the *.bbl file should also be deleted after the special characters in the URL are changed according to @Andy Clifton's answer, and then compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, an alternative solution is simply to replace the "%20" by a space (" ") since "%20" represents a space in an encoded URL.